# $G/Z(G) \cong \mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_p$ then $p||Z(G)|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Problem**

Let $G$ be a finite group with $G/Z(G) \cong \mathbb Z_{p} \times \mathbb Z_{p}$. Then $p| |Z(G)|$.

**My attempt at a solution**

Consider the action of $G$ on itself by conjugation. By the class equation, we have $$|G|=|Z(G)|+\sum_{i=1}^r [G:C_G(x_i)], \space [G:C_G(x_i)]>1$$
It is easy to see that $Z(G) \leq C_G(x)$ for all $x$ so, by Lagrange theorem, $|Z(G)| | |C_G(x)|$. As $|C_G(X)|||G|=|Z(G)|p^2$, it follows $\dfrac{|C_G(x)|}{|Z(G)|}|p^2$.

We can write $[G:C_G(x_i)]=\dfrac{[G:Z(G)]}{[C_G(x_i):Z(G)]}=\dfrac{p^2}{[C_G(x_i):Z(G)]}$ Since $[G:C_G(x_i)]>1$ for $i=1,...,r$, and by the last equality, we have $p| [G:C_G(x_i)]$ for $i=1,...,r$. But then we also have $p||G|$. As $p$ divides $|G|$ and $\sum_{i=1}^r [G:C_G(x_i)]$, it follows $p$ divides $Z(G)$.

I am not sure if my solution is correct, I would appreciate corrections, improvement, or an alternative answer if anyone feels like sharing a different solution.

Edition: I've realized I am not so sure how to properly justify the sentence "...$|Z(G)| | |C_G(x)|$. As $|C_G(X)|||G|=|Z(G)|p^2$, it follows $\dfrac{|C_G(x)|}{|Z(G)|}|p^2$...", any help with that part would also be appreciated.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your proof myself! You seem to have justified everything!

Comment: There is no problem justifying the claim you were worried about. Note that $Z(G)$ is a subgroup of $C_{G}(x)$ for each $x \in G.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $p$ does not divide $Z(G)$ and $P$ be a sylow $p$ subgroup of $G$ then,

$Z(G)\cap P=e$ and $G/Z(G)\cong P$ thus $G=Z(G)P$ as center normilize every subgroup

$$G=Z(G)\times P$$

Then $$Z(G)=Z(Z(G))\times Z(P)=Z(G)\times Z(P)$$

Which means $Z(P)$ is trivial which is a contradiction.

**Note:** Your solution is true, you can take this solution as an alternative way.

Comment: Nice proof +1 from me.